# converting a blender physics simulation into an fbx animation

Tags: animation, unity

I have a dynamic paint simulation to create a series of waves. I've baked that animation and now I'm trying to get it into Unity some how. I've tried using the AnimAll extension, however the simulation doesn't affect the mesh itself in edit mode, so it wont work that way.

Any suggestions on how I can make this work?

thanks

Comment: Dynamic paint creates textures not mesh deforms, if you bake to an image sequence you should be able to use that as a normal/displacement map in unity.